# Workflow edit but not publish

Tags: 7, workflows

I am using workflow module to manage article moderation. I have created different state for that and for each state, I have set permissions using workflow content access.

Now, when an article is flagged, I am changing it's workflow state to say "s1" and unpublished the content.

In this state, author's can allow to edit the content but not publish it, the edited content will be sent to admin for review.

Now when I go to edit tab, it is showing "Publish" button too, by which author can Publish the content.

How can I remove these buttons ? Also is there any way, I can show workflow comment box in edit node page only.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Publish' button isn't determined by the **state** of the node according to your workflow.  Actually, whether the 'Publish' button appears is determined by the **permissions** you have as a user.

So if *you* look at the content in the s1 state, you may see the 'Publish' button, because you're an admin.  An author looking at that same piece of content in the s1 state, however, shouldn't see that button based on the workflow moderation permissions you've given them.  Does that make sense?  It's not the workflow state, but the individual's permissions that determine whether that button is available.

So test it out by logging in as an **author** to see what they would see.  If you can still see the 'Publish' button when you're logged in as an author, that may mean that you've inadvertently given that role a permission you didn't intend, such as 'Administer content', so double-check the permissions again.  :0)

My authors definitely can't publish in some of my workflow states!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the publish button is appearing even if I logged in as author. Can you tell me which permission should I revoke from author.

Comment: Does the author role have the 'Administer content' permission I mention above?

Comment: No, only Administrator has that permission. But author has edit own content permission.